# Изменить видимость блока в модальном окне

Tags: html, jquery, css

Доброе время.

Как правильно убрать/скрыть `div class="aside"` со страницы, при ее открытии в модальном окне?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Есть страница `#modal >.modal >.aside`

В модальном окне нужно получить `#modal > .modal`

Answer (score 1):

```js
var _button = document.querySelector("button._button");
var _notebook = document.querySelector("body");
_button.addEventListener("click",function(){
document.body.style.overflow = "hidden";
var _aside = document.querySelector("aside.aside_canvas");
var _output = document.createElement("aside");
 _output.className = "aside_canvas";
_output.innerHTML = '<ul class="ul_canvas"><li class="blue" data-color="hsla(243,100%,54%,1)">красный</li><li class="green" data-color="hsla(100,100%,30%,1)">зелёный</li><li class="red" data-color="hsla(358,100%,50%,1)">синий</li><li class="black" data-color="hsla(0,0%,0%,1)">черный</li><li class="lastuk" data-color="hsla(0,0%,100%,1)">ластик</li><li class="size_1" data-size="1">размер 1</li><li class="size_5" data-size="5">размер 5</li><li class="size_10" data-size="10">размер 10</li><li class="size_15" data-size="15">размер 15</li></ul><hr class="hr"><figure id="figure"><canvas id="canvas"></canvas></figure><hr class="hr"><ul class="ul_bottom"><li class="li_u">нажмите левую кнопку мышки и рисуйте</li><li class="li_o" data-bottom="clear">очистить</li>  <li class="li_z" data-bottom="close">закрыть</li></ul>';
_button.insertAdjacentElement("beforeBegin",_output);


var tect = document.getElementById('figure');
if(tect){
var figure,canvas,context;
    figure = document.getElementById('figure');
    canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
 context = canvas.getContext('2d');
 size();
 canvas.addEventListener("mousedown",startDrawing,false);
    canvas.addEventListener("mouseup",stopDrawing,false);
    canvas.addEventListener("mouseout",stopDrawing,false);
    canvas.addEventListener("mousemove",draw,false);
    document.body.addEventListener("resize",size,false);
 
  var previousColorElement;
function changeColor(color,imgElement){ 
         context.strokeStyle = color;
         imgElement.style.borderBottom = "2px solid #00ffff";
         if (previousColorElement != null){
    previousColorElement.style.borderBottom = "2px solid hsla(40,90%,20%,1)";
   } 
    previousColorElement = imgElement;
}
    var previousThicknessElement;
function changeThickness(thickness,imgElement){
        context.lineWidth = thickness;
        imgElement.style.borderBottom = "2px solid #00ffff";
       if (previousThicknessElement != null){
        previousThicknessElement.style.borderBottom = "2px solid hsla(40,90%,20%,1)";
       }
        previousThicknessElement = imgElement;
}
function size(e){
 var w = figure.scrollWidth;
 var h = figure.scrollHeight;
 canvas.setAttribute("width",w);
 canvas.setAttribute("height",h);
   }
  var isDrawing = false;
function startDrawing(e){
         isDrawing = true;
         context.beginPath();
         context.moveTo(e.pageX - canvas.offsetLeft, e.pageY - canvas.offsetTop);
} 

function draw(e) {
     if (isDrawing == true){
     context.lineTo(e.pageX - canvas.offsetLeft, e.pageY - canvas.offsetTop);
        context.stroke();
       }
} 

function stopDrawing(){
         isDrawing = false;
         }
  
function clearCanvas(){
         context.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
}

function saveCanvas(){
var imageCopy = document.getElementById("savedImageCopy");
imageCopy.src = canvas.toDataURL();
var imageContainer = document.getElementById("savedCopyContainer");
imageContainer.style.display = "block";
}
var _ul_pad = document.querySelector("ul.ul_canvas");
if(_ul_pad){
 _ul_pad.addEventListener("click",function(){
 var event = event || window.event;
 var target = event.target || event.srcElement;
 if(target.hasAttribute("data-color") && target.tagName == "LI"){
 changeColor(target.getAttribute("data-color"),target);
 }else{changeThickness(target.getAttribute("data-size"),target)};
 },false);};
var _ul_pad_bot = document.querySelector("ul.ul_bottom");
if(_ul_pad_bot){
_ul_pad_bot.addEventListener("click",function(){
var event = event || window.event;
var target = event.target || event.srcElement;
 if(target.hasAttribute("data-bottom") && target.getAttribute("data-bottom") == "clear"){
  clearCanvas();
 }
 else if(target.hasAttribute("data-bottom") && target.getAttribute("data-bottom") == "save"){
  saveCanvas();
 }
 else if(target.hasAttribute("data-bottom") && target.getAttribute("data-bottom") == "close"){
 document.querySelector("aside.aside_canvas").parentNode.removeChild(document.querySelector("aside.aside_canvas"));
 document.body.style.overflow = "";
 };
},false);};
};

},false);
```

```css
html,body,aside,canvas,figure,ul,li
{
margin:0;
padding:0;
border:0;
outline:0;
font-size:100%;
font-style:normal;
font-variant:normal;
font-weight:normal;
vertical-align:baseline;
line-height:1;
color:hsla(0,0%,0%,1);
background:transparent;
}
html{width:calc(100%);height:calc(100%);}
body
{
font:normal 100%/1 'Times New Roman',sans-serif;
text-overflow: ellipsis;
background:hsla(0,0%,60%,.8);
}        
ol,ul{list-style:none;}

aside.aside_canvas{ border:1px solid hsla(0,0%,0%,1);
width:98%;
height:100%;
margin:0 auto;
padding:.5%;
background:hsla(80,79%,70%,1);
overflow:hidden;
}
.aside_canvas ul.ul_canvas{ 
 border:1px solid hsla(0,0%,85%,1);
    width:99.9%;
    height:1.5em;
    margin:0 auto;
    padding:.5% 0 0 0;
    margin-bottom:1%;
    border-bottom:2px solid hsla(40,90%,20%,1);
    background:hsla(60,10%,80%,1);
    box-shadow:5px 6px 6px hsla(0,0%,20%,.8);
}
ul.ul_canvas .blue{background:#0000ff;}
ul.ul_canvas .green{background:#008000;}
ul.ul_canvas .red{background:#ff0000;}
ul.ul_canvas .black{background:#000000;}
ul.ul_canvas .lastuk{background:#b4b400;}
ul.ul_canvas li{
    float:left;
    width:10%;
    height:2em;
    margin:0 0 0 .8%;
    margin-bottom:.7%;
    padding:0;
    border:1px solid #fff;
 font:italic 100 140%/1.8 'Times New Roman',sans-serif;
   text-align:center;
    color:hsla(0,0%,100%,1);
    text-shadow:1px -1px 1px hsla(0,0%,0%,.9);
    border-bottom:2px solid hsla(40,90%,20%,1);
    box-shadow:5px 6px 6px hsla(0,0%,20%,.8);
    background:hsla(60,10%,40%,1);
    
}
li:hover{cursor: pointer;}                             
figure{
    background:#faebd7;
    width:100%;
    height:80vh;
    margin:0 auto;
   overflow:hidden;
}
canvas{
    background:#ffffff;
    border:1px solid transparent;
   cursor: crosshair;
}
#savedCopyContainer{display:none;}
/*НИЖНИЕ КНОПКИ*/
.aside_canvas ul.ul_bottom{ 
    border:1px solid hsla(0,0%,85%,1);
    width:99.9%;
    height:1.5em;
    margin:0 auto;
    padding:0 0 .5% 0;
   margin-top:3.5%;
   border-top:2px solid hsla(40,90%,20%,1);
    background:hsla(60,10%,80%,1);
    box-shadow:5px -6px 6px hsla(0,0%,20%,.8);
}
ul.ul_bottom li{
    float:left;
    width:10%;
    height:2em;
    margin:0 0 0 .8%;
    margin-top:-2%;
    padding:0;
    border:1px solid #fff;
    border-top:2px solid hsla(40,90%,20%,1);
    font:italic 100 140%/1.8 'Times New Roman',sans-serif;
   text-align:center;
    color:hsla(0,0%,100%,1);
    text-shadow:1px -1px 1px hsla(0,0%,0%,.9);
    box-shadow:5px -6px 6px hsla(0,0%,20%,.8);
    background:hsla(60,10%,60%,1);
   transition:all .4s linear 0s;
}
li.li_o:hover,.li_c:hover,.li_z:hover
{
background:#ff7920;
}
ul.ul_bottom li.li_o{
    width:15.5%;
}
ul.ul_bottom li.li_c{
    width:15.5%;
}
ul.ul_bottom li.li_u{
    width:36%;
   height:1.5em;
   margin:0;
   padding:0;
   border:none;
   box-shadow:none;
   color:hsla(0,0%,0%,1);
   background:hsla(60,10%,80%,1);
   font-size:120%;
   cursor: text;
}
ul.ul_bottom li.li_z{
   width:15.5%;
 }
button._button
{
display:block;
width:25%;
height:2em;
margin:30% auto;
padding:0;
border:1px solid #fff;
border-top:2px solid hsla(40,90%,20%,1);
font:italic 100 140%/1.8 'Times New Roman',sans-serif;
text-align:center;
color:hsla(0,0%,100%,1);
text-shadow:1px -1px 1px hsla(0,0%,0%,.9);
box-shadow:5px -6px 6px hsla(0,0%,20%,.8);
background:hsla(60,10%,60%,1);
}
```

```html
<button class="_button">Открыть</button>
```

Comment: Пример проверяйте развернутым на всю страницу.

Comment: Некогда было делать адаптивность. Принцип работы создаём узел aside вставляем на страницу затем удаляем методом removeChild()

Answer (score 0):

Сложно ответить точно, не имея примера кода. Однако простейший способ скрыть блок - применить к нему CSS правило `display: none`.

Comment: .modal .aside
{
 display:none !important;
} не работает

Comment: @AndrewYarmolenko уберите запятую после aside. А во вторых - что сложно в том, чтобы проинспектировать код и выявить, какой класс перебивает?

Comment: запятая там лишняя конечно, если инспектировать, то display:none работает, а при повторном вызове модалки display:none уже не работает.

Answer (score 0):

1) Открывать в модальном окне `iframe` с GET-параметром, например http://example.com?noaside=1

2) В открываемом URL проверять наличие параметра и при необходимости добавлять код CSS, скрывающий `aside` или вообще не выводить aside на бекэнде.

Answer (score 0):

```
document.querySelector("div.aside").parentNode.removeChild( document.querySelector("div.aside") );
```

Comment: Сделайте, пожалуйста, хотя бы краткое описание что этот код будет делать.

Comment: Пожалуйста, добавьте в ваш ответ описание кода, чтобы пользователям было легче его понять. Для редактирования ответа, нажмите [Edit]. Так же можете ознакомиться с советами о том, [как написать хороший ответ](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). - [Из очереди проверок](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/148458)

Comment: Краткое описание кода. Чтобы не лазить в админку, решили через модалку вызывать страницу редактирования категории прямо с сайта, но при загрузки отображается полностью админ страница и необходимо убрать лишнее в данном случае .aside, как-то так.